# How to mix all sound to make it become complete song?

Tags: production, electronic-music, beginner

I just start to become EDM artist.These is something i can't get it. why this song: https://splice.com/marshmello/alone-contest  , I mean, how did they mix all that sound to become one song really good? How they create sound make song more hear so good? what is the tutorial when create an EDM song like Alone? just tell me how they make edm song, and from that i will figure it out.

Comment: Hey fastestsuperman. Are you able to offer a little more information on your experience, what audio software / DAW you're using, what platform (Mac/PC) etc?

Comment: While Skarik's answer is an excellent start point, this question is incredibly broad, and could have a wide number of equally good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you've said you've just started to become an EDM artist, the nature of your question seems to suggest that you're at the stage before that; you'd like to make EDM, but don't know where to begin. As such, I'll respond to the question with that in mind, and give you the *bare-bone basics*.

I started to write everything out, but this kind of subject has been addressed thousands of times on the internet already, so instead will offer a helpful selection of links for you to look at.

- [WikiHow page](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Music-Using-a-Computer) on the basics of starting out making music on your computer.
- [MusicTech page](http://www.musictech.net/2013/06/beginners-guide/) on the basics of starting out making music on your computer.
- [MusicRadar article](http://www.musicradar.com/tuition/tech/the-beginners-guide-to-daws-182337#) on free / low budget 'beginner' DAWs, should those mentioned in the above articles (Ableton, ProTools, Logic, etc) be out of budget.

Once you've chosen a DAW and have a basic setup, you can start to look on YouTube for tutorials. Again, there are thousands of useful videos on there, from basic beginner tutorials, to advanced synth programming and effect-use. You may want to take a look at the below:

- [Learning to Produce Electronic Music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYNMd3Mnkhs) is a good video that explains some of the basics, suggests learning a little music and mixing theory before jumping into making music, and offers helpful links for each stage he discusses.
- There are numerous tutorial series for how to create an EDM track from start to finish, using various different DAWs. [Here's one on Ableton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foNlvcwzv30).

It is essential that you listen to lots of music in the genre you plan to create, and pick them apart and analyse it; listen to the structure of the music, the build ups, the drops, the use of percussion, the placement and choice of instruments, the effects used, etc. The kind of link that you posted above is very helpful for this kind of thing as there is a visual representation of each track in that song, so you can see when different instruments and samples are playing.

The important thing to remember though is that whilst there are step-by-step guides on how to make music and use software, **there is no specific forumla on how to make a good song.** The best music is usually created by those who have a creative mind, a good understanding of music theory and the software they use,  and are able to put this all together to turn an idea they've had into music that others can listen to.